# upload flash air integrated admob ane failed

Tags: upload, air, admob, ane

I created app with flash cc and have packed ipa success,and test it on ios8 device.
but upload fail when  submit to appstore.
I integrated admob ane( https://github.com/lilili87222/admob-ane ) for flash air in my app,
I am not sure weather caused by the ane lib. 
any body have the same error?

```
ERROR ITMS-9000: \"Invalid Segment Alignment. This app does not have proper segment         alignment and should be rebuilt with the latest version of Xcode. Please contact Developer   Technical Support if you need further assistance.\"
```

Comment: Try this ANE: https://code.google.com/p/flash-air-admob-ane-for-ios-and-android/

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for Adobe to resolve this issue too...seems like the air linker in air 15 is outdated
and no longer accepted by apple.

Answer (score 0):

Update you Adobe AIR SDK from http://labs.adobe.com there 15.0.0.302 from 2 oct that allow submit apps